# Why use size of character pointer

Tags: c

> What is the meaning of this statement?

```
char *str[10];
```

Why do we need to specify the size?

Comment: It's an array of 10 pointer-to-char.

Comment: Because an array is not a pointer! How about learning from a good book?

Comment: In other words: it specifies the size of an array containing pointers, not the size of a pointer.

Comment: Do you agree `str` is an array?  How big an array do you want?

Comment: char *name = "David Malan" works.  But >char *name;  >gets(name);  doesn't. That's what I am asking.

Comment: @AayushSharma: In the first case, you're telling `name` to point to the string literal `"David Malan"`, which is stored as an array of `char` somewhere in your program image.  In the second case, you're telling `gets` (which you should *NEVER NEVER EVER* use, btw) to store input into the buffer pointed to by `name`, except `name` doesn't point anywhere meaningful yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @JohnBode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted in the comments, `char *str[10];` depicts an array of `char` pointers.  This would be useful, for example, if the length of strings this object will contain is not known until run-time.  Once at run-time, it is determined that the length of string for each `char *` needs to be 25 (for example), then memory can be dynamically created on the heap:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    str[i] = calloc(26,1);//room for 25 char plus NULL terminator for each char *
}
```

If string length *is* known before run-time, then the array of char arrays can be created on the stack as:

```
char str[10][26]
```

Either of these methods work to create arrays of strings.  The first method requires that memory be freed when finished using the object:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if(str[i]) free(str[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why size is provided is actually a basic rule. Then you must ask why `int` is used for storing integers. From C complete Reference Book

> **In C89, the size of an array must be specified using a constant expression. Thus, in C89, the size of
>   an array is fixed at compile time.** C99 allows arrays whose sizes are determined at run time.